# How to delete sleep process in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I found that my mysql sever have many of connection who is sleep. i want to delete them all.

so how i can configure my mysql server than then delete or dispose the connection who is in sleep not currently in process.

are this possible to delete this thing in mysql tell me how i can do following

a connection allow only one time datareader open and destroy the connection [process] after giving resposnse of query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to delete a sleeping thread? MySQL creates threads for connection requests, and when the client disconnects the thread is put back into the cache and waits for another connection.

This reduces a lot of overhead of creating threads 'on-demand', and it's nothing to worry about. A sleeping thread uses about 256k of memory.

Comment: Are their is no problem with sleep thread. are you sure other connection i make future never have affect for old sleep thread.

Comment: A sleeping thread will become active when a new client tries to connect. MySQL will then serve the sleeping thread (making it active) to the client.

Comment: No, "Sleep" connection also count as a connection, and it will effect to exceed the maximum possible connection.

Comment: This may have changed since I posted my comment, but from my reading at the time a sleeping thread is exactly that - waiting for someone to connect and then it becomes active.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it manually you can do like this:

login to Mysql as admin:

```
 mysql -uroot -ppassword;
```

And than run command:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

You will get something like below :

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host               | db       | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 49 | application | 192.168.44.1:51718 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  183 |       | NULL             ||
| 55 | application | 192.168.44.1:51769 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 56 | application | 192.168.44.1:51770 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 57 | application | 192.168.44.1:51771 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 58 | application | 192.168.44.1:51968 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |   11 |       | NULL             |
| 59 | root        | localhost          | NULL     | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

You will see complete details of different connections. Now you can kill the sleeping connection as below:

```
mysql> kill 52;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can find all working process execute the sql:

```
show process;
```

and you will find the sleep process, if you want terminate it, please remember the processid and excute this sql:

```
kill processid
```

but actually you can set a timeout variable in my.cnf:

```
wait_timeout=15
connect_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=100
```

Comment: Well my code open many connection block by block and i thing they forget to close connection they open and they still use the server process so i can't do anything. as a rule i can change only configuration setting. that's possible for me. well thanks.

Comment: setting this timeout will kill only sleeping processes or will also kill the processes executing more than time out setting , i have set timeout = 30 sec ,and a query or procedure takes more than 30 sec

Answer (score 0):

for me with MySql server on windows,

I update the file (because cannot set variable with sql request due privileges):

```
D:\MySQL\mysql-5.6.48-winx64\my.ini
```

add the lines:

```
wait_timeout=61
interactive_timeout=61
```

restart service, and acknowledge new values with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%_timeout';
```

==> i do a connection tests and after 1 minutes all 10+ connections in sleep are disapeared!